# Is 'if (!array.includes(item))' the correct JavaScript syntax for checking whether an array Does Not contain an item?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the usual (array.includes(item)) syntax for the reverse purpose--checking whether an item is not included in an array, just by adding the exclamation in front of the array; but it seems to have broken my code.  Is this syntactically incorrect? If so, what is the proper syntax?

```
if (!domains.includes(domain)) { 
 return 
    }
  })
```

Comment: if you don't have anything wrapping this code then you need to remove `})`

Comment: "_it seems to have broken my code_". How? Is there error message(s) in the dev console?

Comment: The `!array.includes(item)` is perfectly fine... if you're sure that `array` is really an array.

Answer (score 3):

Using ! should work. For instance in the code below:

```js
let greetings = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Bonjour'];

if(!greetings.includes('Hola')) {
  console.log("Hola is not a part of the greetings!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can check that way. If you add an `!` before the condition check, it checks whether that item *does not* exist in the array. In your case, syntax-error of extra parenthesis could be the issue, otherwise it should work.
See this:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 5];

if(!arr.includes(3)){
  console.log('it works')
}


if(arr.includes(5)){
  console.log('this works too')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also the some method that tells if an array contains an item that meets a condition, useful if your array contains reference objects. Includes only work for value objects or finding the reference of an object.

```
if (!domains.some(d => d === domain)) {
}
```

Comment: Which is what I mean by finding the reference of an object.

Comment: Oh, yes, I understand now.